# How can I deny a get request if in the request is present a specific string?

Tags: get

An abusive website has stolen a embed code of mine live chat, this code has been used in a website that is now consuming traffic on my server.

Even if i locked the chat widget to be used from an unauthorized domain, using CORS rules, I get sometimes some server GET request that I want to block, deny.

`GET /livechat/index.php/ita/widgetrestapi/settings?tz=Asia%2FShanghai&l=%252F%252F**badsite.domain.cn**%252Fd%252F41-miui125%252F(vela)&dt=MIUI12.5%2520%25E5%2585%25A8%25E8%25AE%25BE%25E5%25A4%2587%25E5%25AE%2598%25E6%2596%25B9%25E6%25B5%258B%25E8%25AF%2595%25E5%259B%25BA%25E4%25BB%25B6%2520-%2520%25E6%2588%2591%25E4%25BB%25AC%25E7%259A%2584DIY%2520-%2520%25E6%259C%2589%25E5%2585%25B4%25E8%25B6%25A3%25EF%25BC%258C%25E4%25BA%25AB%25E4%25B9%2590%25E8%25B6%25A3&theme=7&mode=popup&pos=api HTTP/1.0`

There is a way I can set an .htaccess rule to deny the GET request when it has inside the bad website URL **badsite.domain.cn** ?

I'm looking for place a code that block GET requests with inside the bad URL string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In htaccess, you can apply below code to prevent that site to process further.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} badsite\.domain\.cn [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} badsite\.domain\.cn [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

**RewriteEngine On**: Enables the Apache mod_rewrite engine.

**RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} badsite.domain.cn [NC,OR]**: This condition checks if the request's hostname (HTTP_HOST) contains "badsite.domain.cn" in a case-insensitive manner (NC). The OR flag indicates that either this condition or the next one must be true.

**RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} badsite.domain.cn [NC]**: This condition checks if the query string (the part of the URL after the "?") contains "badsite.domain.cn" in a case-insensitive manner (NC).

**RewriteRule .* - [F,L]**: If either of the two conditions is true, this rule is applied. It returns a 403 Forbidden status (F) to deny access to the request and stops processing further rules (L).

Comment: This code saved me from an attack. A question: this code can be also reverted? I mean can I authorize just few domain I have and deny every get request that is not from a string whitelisted using another code?